# Sum of a finite arithmetic sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Let $S_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2j(2j-1)x^{2j}$ where $|x| < 1$. What is the finite sum corresponds to?

Edit:
\begin{equation*}
S_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2j(2j-1)x^{2j}\\
 = x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1 - x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\right]
\end{equation*}

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I can't think of a way of proceeding. Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2j(2j-1)x^{2j}=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x^2)^j\right).$$
where the finite sum on the right has a closed formula that you should know (see [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation)).

Can you take it from here? Please show your effort: edit your question and, below it, write about your progress  toward the final answer!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But still I can't think how to proceed this. Why you have written it like this?

Comment: The sum on the right has a closed formula that you should know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Comment: I can solve the sum in RHS. But how did you come up with this overall equation?

Comment: Brilliant idea! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @RobertZ: I think I got the logic. Thanks.

Comment: @Shana Why don't you edit your question and, below it, you write about your progress? Otherwise I am afraid that your question will be closed...

Comment: I have edited the question. However the derivatives are so messy. Is there an elegant solution?